# How to make a DIV centered and has almost a 100% width and a 100% height

Tags: html, css

```
  <div class="main"></div>
   <style>
        .main{ background-color:black;
               position:absolute;
               width:???;
               height:??;
   </style>
```

How to center the div `main` and make its height and width almost 100% with 20px gap from each side of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now define this css

```
<style>
   .main{ 
       background-color:black;
       position:absolute;
       margin:20px;
       left:0;
       right:0;
       top:0;
       bottom:0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The width of a block element is already 100% by default.

All you need do is add padding or margin to create your "gap".

```
<style>
    .main{ background-color:black;
           position:absolute;
           margin: 0 20px;
           height:100%;
      }
</style>
```

### edit

I missed your absolute positioning.
With absolute positioning, I'd use this:

```
#main {
background: #a00;
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 50px; 
right: 50px;
height: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/Ch7FA/)

Comment: OP said "*20px gap from each side of the screen.*"

Comment: @HarmeetSingh The original CSS will work for a standard block level element. With absolute positioning.. see the edit I just made.

Answer (score 0):

This would center align the `div` with 50px space on left and right side.

```
.main {
    margin: 0 50px;  /* [top,bottom] [left,rigth] shorthand syntax */
    width : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
<style>
   .main{ background-color:black;
          position:absolute;
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          margin:20px;
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `calc()` attribute in CSS3:

```
.main
{ 
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:black;
    color: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);  /*repeat with other browsers codes*/
}
```

This tells the div to be 100% wide/high but remove 20px while keeping it in the center.

IT can be used in IE9 (not below)m Firefox 4.0, Chrome 19 and Safari 6. So it might not be the best solution..

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/wVUat/

Comment: I like how you approached the issue. Nice job. Unfortunately it's not widely supported.

Comment: Yeah, not widely supported yet. In about 6 months I suppose :) Or when every IE user stops using <IE9 (forever to go.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using absolute positioning you could try this:

```
<div class="main"></div>

<style>
.main {
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 20px;
right: 20px;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about solution below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #mask {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            opacity: 0.5;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            right: 20px;
            bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mask" />
</body>
</html>
```

Please find it at http://jsfiddle.net/balkon_smoke/yPF8Y/2/